# With Excel VBA is there a way to copy an entire worksheet's NumberFormat to a new worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba, number-formatting

In Excel is there a way to copy the NumberFormat from an input range with multiple columns to an output range of the same number of columns?

I've tried the several variants in this code sample but there's either no change to the output range's formatting when I try to source it from multiple columns, or the performance of copying the values is too problematic.

```
Sub Import()
    'Demonstration variables
    Dim ws_input As Worksheet: Set ws_input = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    Dim ws_output As Worksheet: Set ws_output = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2)
    Dim rowLast As Double, colLast As Double, i As Double

    rowLast = ws_input.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    colLast = ws_input.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    'This variant is way too much of a performance hit and Excel can misapply formatting
    'E.g. Cell XFD1048576 is considered used
    ws_input.Cells.Copy Destination:=ws_output.Range("A1")

    'This variant can copy "###" as the value if the input cell widths are too small
    ws_output.Range("A1", Cells(rowLast, colLast).Address).Value = _
        ws_input.Range("A1", Cells(rowLast, colLast).Address).Value

    'This variant copies values correctly but without formatting
    ws_output.Range("A1", Cells(rowLast, colLast).Address).Value2 = _
        ws_input.Range("A1", Cells(rowLast, colLast).Address).Value2
    ws_output.Range("A1", Cells(rowLast, colLast).Address).NumberFormat  = _
        ws_input.Range("A1", Cells(rowLast, colLast).Address).NumberFormat

    'This variant also seemingly does nothing with the NumberFormat
    ws_output.Range("A1", Cells(rowLast, colLast).Address).EntireColumn.NumberFormat  = _
        ws_input.Range("A1", Cells(rowLast, colLast).Address).EntireColumn.NumberFormat

    'This variant also seemingly does nothing with the NumberFormat
    ws_output.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.NumberFormat = _
        ws_input.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.NumberFormat

    'Kludgy solution I've come to
    For i = 1 to colLast
        ws_output.Columns(i).NumberFormat = ws_input.Columns(i).NumberFormat
    Next i
End Sub
```

I'm hoping to avoid having to use an iterator every time I need to apply number formatting, and it seems like there should be a more intuitive way that Excel can apply the NumberFormat property to multiple ranges from multiple ranges. If I only wanted to source one range as the format, `ws_output.Range("A1:Z9999").NumberFormat = ws_input.Range("A1").NumberFormat` works, but it seems to break down as soon as multiple column sources are used.

Thank you for your time! I greatly appreciate any help on this topic.

Comment: You can copy and paste formats. `Range("A1").PasteSpecial xllPasteFormats`

Comment: `ws_input.UsedRange.Copy Destination:=ws_output.Range("A1")` - don't copy the whole sheet. `"'E.g. Cell XFD1048576 is considered used"` - actually, `ws_input.Cells` is the whole sheet, it has nothing to do with used or not.

Comment: Or use `rowLast` and `colLast` to delineate the range to be copied...

Comment: @BigBen So I wish Microsoft had a KB number on this article, but basically Excel will misapply the formatting and consider cells, even without data, used all the way to the end. This is where you'll see a sheet at 40MB large.

But for that reason, you can see the second variant uses the variables to identify which rows/columns to bring over. The default "Copy" function has a lot of overhead as it copies out all the range properties which we're trying to avoid. In large files, this is a huge performance hit.

Comment: @m_zardos - `worksheet.Cells` is the *entire* worksheet. You can use `UsedRange`, which does have issues. Or use `rowLast` and `colLast` to delineate the range to be copied. Value transfer (the second option) is most certainly faster, but if you are going that route, then you might as well just copy/pastespecial values and number formatting. Or you'll have to loop over the columns to grab the number format.

Comment: @BigBen Which is why I use `.value2` to copy the data. Copy isn't efficient for large sheets, I could perform a `.value` and then `value2` assignment faster than `.copy` - `UsedRange` or no.

Comment: I agree that Value transfer is efficient, but if you're going that route, you'll have to loop. From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.numberformat): "This property returns **Null** if all cells in the specified range don't have the same number format"

Comment: @BigBen amazing catch, I've looked through those docs before and I can't believe that never stuck. Thank you! I'm going to run some stress tests on a few variations now from this and see what works best for performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [`Range.NumberFormat`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.numberformat) docs:

> This property returns **Null** if all cells in the specified range don't have the same number format.

If your columns have different number formats, then you'll have to loop over them as in your last approach, assuming you do not want to use the clipboard.